# How to handle deserialization of empty string into long in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

The below illustration represents building Object of type `TestClass2` using object of type `TestClass1` with the help of Serialization/Deserialization.

`TestClass1` and `TestClass2` have the same structure except one of the members is string in `TestClass1` but long in `TestClass2`.

```
public class TestClass1
{
    public string strlong;
}

public class TestClass2
{
    public long strlong;
}

TestClass1 objT1 = new TestClass1();
objT1.strlong = "20134567";
TestClass2 objT2;
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string JSON1 = serializer.Serialize(objT1);
objT2 = serializer.Deserialize<TestClass2>(JSON1);
```

After the operation, `objT2` will have the values of `objT1` but `strlong` will now be long as opposed to string.

The problem is, if the `strlong` value in `objT1` is an empty string --> "", the deserialization fails with an exception `"" is not a valid value for Int64`.

If `strlong` is non empty string with just numeric characters, the current deserialization works. But I do not know the workaround when something like empty string appears.

For now, lets assume that

1. `strlong` will be in the range of long
2. Will just be a sequence of numeric characters i.e. it will not have `.` or `,` or `/` or any type of other characters
3. Have access to only objects for serialization and I cannot make modifications to `TestClass1` or `TestClass2`.

If there is a simple way (or not) of Creating objects of one class using objects of another class, please mention that in the comments.

**EDIT-Extending the logic**

To extend the logic of solution given in the Answer below to Classes containing members of type other classes, I have used the serialization solution given below to the member items as well. In other words, if classes contain members of other classes, is there a better way of handling the deeper levels than the code below?

```
// **Item1 :** 
// These are the subclasses and classes
// whose objects I am trying to serialize
// and deserialize from one type to another
public class SubClass1
{
    public string toomuch;
    public int number = 30;
}

public class SubClass2
{
    public long toomuch;
    public int number;
}

public class TestClass1
{
    public string strlong;
    public SubClass1 item2;
}

public class TestClass2
{
    public long strlong;
    public SubClass2 item2;
}

// **Item2 :** 
// Solution from StackOverflow for serialization of 
// empty string
public class TestClass1Converter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get { return new Type[] { typeof(TestClass1) }; }
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        var data = obj as TestClass1;
        var dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        if (data == null)
        {
            return dic;
        }

        long val = 0;
        long.TryParse(data.strlong, out val);
        dic.Add("strlong", val);

        // **Item3 :** 
        // trying to serialize and deserialize item2 which is of type SubClass1
        // which might also have empty string
        /*******************/
        JavaScriptSerializer subClassSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        subClassSerializer.RegisterConverters(new[] { new SubClass1Converter() });
        string JSONstr = subClassSerializer.Serialize(data.item2);
        dic.Add("item2", subClassSerializer.Deserialize<SubClass2>(JSONstr));
        /*******************/

        return dic;
    }

    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

// **Item4 :** 
// Serialization for subclass
public class SubClass1Converter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get { return new Type[] { typeof(SubClass1) }; }
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        var data = obj as SubClass1;
        var dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        if (data == null)
        {
            return dic;
        }

        long val = 0;
        long.TryParse(data.toomuch, out val);
        dic.Add("toomuch", val);
        dic.Add("number", data.number);
        return dic;
    }

    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestClass1 objT1 = new TestClass1();
        objT1.strlong = "";
        SubClass1 objSub = new SubClass1();
        objSub.toomuch = "";
        objT1.item2 = objSub;
        TestClass2 objT2;


        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        serializer.RegisterConverters(new[] { new TestClass1Converter() });
        string JSON1 = serializer.Serialize(objT1);
        objT2 = serializer.Deserialize<TestClass2>(JSON1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare your `TestClass2.strlong` as nullable.

```
public class TestClass2
{
    public long? strlong;
}
```

Now you can have `null` in case when the `TestClass1.strlong` is empty string or null.

Here is **UPDATE** in case that you haven't access to modify the classes.

You should add to the serializer the converter via `RegisterConverters` to customize conversion. Here is the example:

```
public class TestClass1Converter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get { return new Type[] { typeof(TestClass1)}; }
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        var data = obj as TestClass1;
        var dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        if(data == null)
        {
            return dic;
        }

        long val = 0;
        long.TryParse(data.strlong, out val);
        dic.Add("strlong", val);
        return dic;
    }

    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This converter will serialize `strlong` to 0 in case when it is not convertible to `long`. You can use it in this way:

```
TestClass1 objT1 = new TestClass1();
objT1.strlong = "444";
TestClass2 objT2;
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.RegisterConverters(new [] {new TestClass1Converter()});
string JSON1 = serializer.Serialize(objT1);
objT2 = serializer.Deserialize<TestClass2>(JSON1);
```

Comment: I cannot make modifications to TestClass1 or TestClass2.

Comment: Thanks Hamlet ! The solution works. I made some edits to the question regarding extension of the logic to classes which might contain members of type other classes. I would appreciate it if you could take a look and let me know of a way to simplify it. If you want me to post it as a new question please let me know.